# jQuery ui.spinner.js global spinner

Tags: jquery, input, html-table, spinner

I am using the jQuery spinner to add +/- values to input fields I have in a table propogated by a mysql database.

I would like to integrate a +/- at the top of the column to +/- 1 to each input in that column as well as each input having its own buttons.

I have tried the following for the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.spinner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery().ready(function($) {
        $('.spinner').spinner({ min: 0, max: 100 });
        $('#spinnerall').spinner().change(function() {$('.spinner').spinner('option', 'max', parseInt($(this).val()));});
        $('#spinnerall').spinner().change(function() {$('.spinner').spinner('option', 'min', parseInt($(this).val()));});
    });
</script>
```

And then this for the table code:

```
<td><input type='text' class='spinner' value='$max' /></td>
<input type='text' id='spinnerall' />
```

The "spinnerall" does not actually need to be an input, but I couldnt figure out anyway to call it otherwise.

The spinnerall input with the code I am using above, resets all of the inputs to equal the same value its currently on, rather than just adding or subtracting 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I can understand the quastion the answer should be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.spinner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var $sa = $('#spinnerall').spinner().change(function() {
        var $me = $(this);
        // we need the offset between the start and current position
        var offset = parseInt($me.attr('data-init')) - parseInt($me.val());
        $ss.each(function(){
            // applying the offset to all spinners
            this.value = parseInt($(this).attr('data-init')) - offset;
            // allow only positive or zero
            this.value *= (this.value > 0);
        })
    });
    $sa.attr('data-init',$sa.val());

    var $ss = $('.spinner').spinner({ min: 0, max: 100 }).change(function(){
        var $me = $(this);
        // replacing the initial value with the current (without the offset)
        $me.attr('data-init',parseInt($me.val()) - parseInt($sa.attr('data-init')) - parseInt($sa.val()));
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

I've tested it with this markup:

```
<input type="text" class="spinner" value="1" /><br/>
<input type="text" class="spinner" value="-5" /><br/>
<input type="text" class="spinner" value="7" /><br/><br/>
<input type='text' id='spinnerall' value="0" />
```

Here's an example in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/vDuxc/2/)

Comment: Hi, one small issue I have found with this is that the values of the inputs should go no lower than 0. When using the individual spinners they stop when you get to 0, but when using the #spinnerall input, it will allow the inputs below to go below 0. At first I thought just to add { min: 0, max: 100 } to the #spinnerall part of the jquery, but that obviously only effected the initial value of the #spinnerall input, which is actually irrelevant. Any ideas?

Comment: Ha-ha this is easy! Just add a line after the line that says `this.value = parseInt($(this).attr('data-init')) - offset;` like `this.value *= (this.value > 0);`